# Have Visual Studio Custom Editor Respond To Key Input

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vssdk

I'm working on a project where i need to create custom editors and use projection buffers for custom code files, i've managed to create a code window by following through the steps in this article
 https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/ripping-the-visual-studio-editor-apart-with-projection-buffers/

[code window image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92GFO.png)

However, I cannot get the code window to respond to any key inputs, using drag and drop works though

The extension is written for visual studio 2015, are their any extra steps that need to be taken care of in order for the code window to work?

This is the code i'm using:

```
 public IWpfTextViewHost CreateEditor(string filePath, int start = 0, int end = 0, bool createProjectedEditor = false)
    {
        //IVsInvisibleEditors are in-memory represenations of typical Visual Studio editors.
        //Language services, highlighting and error squiggles are hooked up to these editors
        //for us once we convert them to WpfTextViews. 
        var invisibleEditor = GetInvisibleEditor(filePath);

        var docDataPointer = IntPtr.Zero;
        Guid guidIVsTextLines = typeof(IVsTextLines).GUID;

        ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(invisibleEditor.GetDocData(
            fEnsureWritable: 1
            , riid: ref guidIVsTextLines
            , ppDocData: out docDataPointer));

        IVsTextLines docData = (IVsTextLines)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(docDataPointer);

        //Create a code window adapter
        var codeWindow = _editorAdapter.CreateVsCodeWindowAdapter(VisualStudioServices.OLEServiceProvider);
        ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(codeWindow.SetBuffer(docData));

        //Get a text view for our editor which we will then use to get the WPF control for that editor.
        IVsTextView textView;
        ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(codeWindow.GetPrimaryView(out textView));

        _currentlyFocusedTextView = textView;


        RegisterDocument(filePath);


        var textViewHost = _editorAdapter.GetWpfTextViewHost(textView);

        return textViewHost;
    }
```